# create options for multiselect attribute dynamically magento

Tags: php, arrays, magento

I am newbie on magento. I written script for creating options for multiselect attribute dynamically.

But it assign red option to product A and yellow option to product B?
I want to assign options to product. Product A has blue,green,red value this should get selected.

If option is not exist for that product and which is not option of multi select then it will call setOrAddOptionAttribute function to create that option.
But dont know where I am doing wrong?

Thanks is advance.

```
    `<?php

$username = "admin2";
$password = "admin002";
$hostname = "10.2.30.119";
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
$selected = mysql_select_db("yuvraj_test", $dbhandle);

echo 'script ..';


require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento

umask(0);
Mage::app();

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE); //enable error reporting
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', (Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

$products = array('65' => array("blue", "green", "red"),
    '66' => array("blue", "green", "red", "pink", "yellow"));



$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'testcolor');
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);//false for default values
}

$attrOptions = array();//key : value of options
$finalArr = array();//list of option value assign to products

foreach ($options as $k => $v) {

    $attrOptions[$v['label']] = $v['value'];

    if (in_array($v['label'], $products[65])) {
        $finalArr[$v['label']][] = 65;
    }

    if (in_array($v['label'], $products[66])) {
        $finalArr[$v['label']][] = 66;
    }
}

$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
$attribute->loadByCode(4, 'testcolor');

foreach ($products as $prod_id => $optArr) {

    foreach ($optArr as $val) {

        if ($attrOptions[$val]) {

            Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_product_action')->updateAttributes($finalArr[$val], array('testcolor' => $attrOptions[$val]), 0);
        } else {
            setOrAddOptionAttribute($val);
            Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_product_action')->updateAttributes($finalArr[$val], array('testcolor' => $attrOptions[$val]), 0);
        }
    }
}

function setOrAddOptionAttribute($arg_value) {

    $attribute_model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
    $attribute_options_model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table');
    $attribute_code = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'testcolor');
    $attribute = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);
    $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute);
    $options = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions(false);
    if (!$value_exists) {
        $attribute->setData('option', array(
            'value' => array(
                'option' => array($arg_value, $arg_value)`enter code here`
            )
        ));
        $attribute->save();
    }
    return true;
}

exit();
?>
```